# How to use an environment variable in the agent section of a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building a Docker image for an application based in node.js where some of the dependencies requires an NPM token for a private NPM registry, but when building the image the variable containing the token is null, e.g.

```
docker build -t 3273e0bfe8dd329a96070382c1c554454ca91f96 --build-args NPM_TOKEN=null -f Dockerfile
```

a simplified pipeline is:

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    NPM_TOKEN = credentials('npm-token')
  }

  agent {
    dockerfile {
      additionalBuildArgs "--build-args NPM_TOKEN=${env.NPM_TOKEN}"
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Lint') { 
      steps { 
        sh 'npm run lint' 
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Is there a way to use the env variable in that section or it is not currently supported?

BTW, I've followed the suggestions in [Docker and private modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/docker-and-private-modules) related to how to use a NPM token to build a docker image

Comment: hey @pablodcar, did you find a workaround except using scripted pipelines?

Comment: @MeidanAlon No other workaround yet

Comment: So two years after your question, they still haven't fixed it, but I answered with a workaround that works with declarative pipelines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is definitely a bug with the declarative pipeline. You can track the issue related to this here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42369

If you move away from using the declarative pipeline and use the scripted pipelines instead, this won't occur, although your Jenkinsfile will be "wordier"

Comment: Would be nice if you show an example for a scripted pipeline which resolves this problem.

Answer (score 3):

found a solution for this. Use credentials manager to add NPM_TOKEN. Then you can do

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:latest'
      args '-e NPM_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('npm install') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    stage('static code analysis') {
      steps {
        sh 'npx eslint .'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Which credentials manager are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a workaround for this and it still uses declarative pipeline.
I'm using this technique to download private github repos with pip.

```
// Workarounds for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42369
// Warning: The secret will show up in your build log, and possibly be in your docker image history as well.
// Don't use this if you have a super-confidential codebase

def get_credential(name) {
  def v;
  withCredentials([[$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: name, variable: 'foo']]) {
      v = env.foo;
  }
  return v
}

def get_additional_build_args() {
    return "--build-arg GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=" + get_credential("mysecretid")
}


pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.test'
            additionalBuildArgs get_additional_build_args()
        }
    }
```