# How to pass environment variables to docker-agent section in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to pass the environment variables from `environment` section to `agent` section in `Jenkinsfile` please note the `agent` will be a `docker container`. Please find the code snippet below

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        DOCKER_REGISTRY = "my-docker-registry"
        DOCKER_IMAGE = "my-docker-image-build"
        BUILD_LABEL = "my-server-to-run-container"
    }
    
    agent {
        docker {
            label "${env.BUILD_LABEL}"
            image "${env.DOCKER_IMAGE}"
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('sample-print-env-variables') {
            steps {
                echo "This is the BUILD Label ${env.BUILD_LABEL}"
                echo "This is the Docker Image ${env.DOCKER_IMAGE}"
                echo "This is the Artifactory URL ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL}"                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet when tried on Jenkins instance (running version 2.319) yields below result

```
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . null

Error: No such object: null
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv (hide)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull null
Using default tag: latest
```

Based on the [Jenkins-Documentation-Syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) the declarative semantics look correct also used [Jenkins-Linter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/) to confirm there are no errors with `Jenkinsfile`.

Any suggestions or inputs to resolve the error are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try removing the `env.` like they do [in this doc here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug with declarative pipelines, the issue was created in 2017 and they still have not fixed it. https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42369

As a workaround, I suggest to use credentials or calling function that returns parameters.

[How to use an environment variable in the agent section of a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052302/how-to-use-an-environment-variable-in-the-agent-section-of-a-jenkins-declarative)